# const struct object access member functions (and an operator overloading question)

Tags: c++, constants

I tried to overload the `<<` operator for my custom `struct`, but encountered `error C2662`, code as follows:

```
struct HP{
    int max_hp;
    int hp;
    HP(int max_hp){
        this->max_hp=max_hp;
        this->hp=max_hp;
    }
    // this const declarative doesn't support const HP& obj argument
    const string repr(){
        stringstream hp_stats;
        hp_stats << this->hp << "/" << this->max_hp; 
        return hp_stats.str();
    }
    // This is fine with const HP& obj argument
    const string repr(){
        stringstream hp_stats;
        hp_stats << this->hp << "/" << this->max_hp; 
        return hp_stats.str();
    } 
};

// would cause error C2662
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const HP& obj){
    out<<obj.repr();
    return out;
}
```

I've found that this is because the implicitly access of `this` pointer, and `const` attempts to convert `*this` into `const *this` and thus fails. But as I changed from `const string repr()` to `string repr() const`, it magically worked and compiled successfully.

1. **What's the difference between a `const T func(){}` and `T func() const`, which makes a const `struct` object invoking feasible?**
2. I read it on cppreference.com, but still unsure **why << overloading has to be declared outside a class scope.**
3. Suppose I have `repr()` member function for `struct HP`, `struct Shield`, etc. I tried to make the << overloading a template function, but it turns that I am overloading << at global scope. **Can I specify the `T` I am about to apply, OR apply the overloading across several classes with same member function, WITHOUT classes defined under one base class?**

```
// complier thinks such overloading is global on <<
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const T& obj){
    out<<obj.repr();
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Why does the `repr` method claim to modify the object?

Comment: Does my `repr()` definition seem to modify the object? I didn't realize. How come?

Comment: A method like `void foo()` implies it modifies the state of the object instance.  A method like `void bar() const` implies it does not modify the state of the object instance.  Either one could be *lying*, but that's bad programming.  C++ gives a programmer enough rope to shoot themself in the foot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `const T func() {}` means that the return type is `const T` and the function might mutate the object. Whereas, `T func() const {}` means that the return type is *non-const* but the object is unaltered (`const`). You can also have both or neither `const`.
2. It doesn't have to be declared outside the class, it can be declared inside as a `friend` (non-member) function. That works here as well. However, for a member function: since `operator<<()`'s first parameter is `ostream&`, you could only declare it in `ostream` and not `HP`, which won't work. Remember, member operators are like `*this` as the *first* argument of non-member operators.
3. Yes, you can do this. The easiest is to delegate to a common print function; the more elegant way is to use `std::enable_if`, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_v<std::is_same_v<T, HP> || std::is_same_v<t, Shield>, ostream&>
operator<<(ostream& out, const T& obj)
{
    out<<obj.repr();
    return out;
}
```

You can also write the conditions as a template and then re-use it:

```
template<typename T>
static constexpr bool is_printable_v = std::is_same_v<T, HP> || std::is_same_v<T, Shield>;

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_v<is_printable_v<T>>, ostream&>
operator<<(ostream& out, const T& obj) { ... }
```

Comment: I tried to apply "write the conditions as a template", but it fails to compile, producing some intractable errors. Should it be rephrased? I really would like it to work, as I require but 7 or 8 `struct` to overload their `<<`.

Comment: @JackLee Sorry, should have written `static constexpr bool`, not `using`.

Comment: That was cool! I should really spend some time digging in these features.  I learned about std::enable_if a while ago. For `std::enable_if_v<bool, type>`, it equals `type` if bool is `true`. So if I entered a type like `string` in condition, would `enable_if` become `void`, and thus nullify the overloading below? How does this mechanism exactly work, to avoid overloading for other `type`?

Comment: @JackLee The keyword you're looking for, 'SFINAE' (Substitution failure is not an error). If `bool` is false, it'll not have any type - it'll be a substitution failure, thus it'll not take place in overload resolution.

Comment: I still know about `static` and `constexpr` at textbook level, and I am trying to play the keywords to learn more. I thought `constexpr` is sort of a optimization other than necessity, as it is implicitly `inline`. Why couldn't template condition compile without it? And what help does `static` do?

Comment: @JackLee The problem (in my code) was `using` vs. `bool`, i.e., declaring type vs. value. But, when you declare a template value, you can save a lot of hassle if it's `static constexpr`. No need to instantiate. Also, `constexpr` notes that the expression/function can be evaluated compile-time. It's both for compiler and for documentation.